# Javascript rolling ISO date back one day on the first of the month

Tags: javascript, php, date, isodate

I am storing an ISO date in a MongoDB collection, and pulling it out using PHP.  When I pull it out, it's accurate to the date (Example: `2014-06-01`).  The PHP driver I am using converts the date to a Unix Timestamp, which is accurate to the date I have inserted (`2014-06-01`).  When I bring it into Javascript, though, the date is shown as the day before (`2014-05-31`).  This happens with any date that I put in that lands on the first day of the month... August 1st rolls back to July 31st, July 1st rolls back to June 30th.

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?  All other dates are accurate, and when I call `toISOString()` on a date that falls on the first of the month, it reflects the accurate date.

Comment: can you add php and javascript code? Data example? with timestamps. Timezones...

Comment: Perhaps the timezone of the client doesn't match the timezone of the server?

Comment: Most likely it's the timezone. If 2014-06-01 is interpreted by JS as midnight UTC and you live west of England, then hours are subtracted and the day is moved one day back.

Comment: @Qualcuno how do I get around this then?  Would I have to set my server to UTC?

Comment: How do you create the date on the client? post the code please @Siraris